# How to reduce execution time using thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a program finding Pointwise mutual information of word pairs. The code I have done is as follows:

```
temp_list = co_occurrence_dict.values()
N=0
for item in temp_list:
N += item

    main_dict = {}
    temp_dict = {}
    for word in all_opinion_words:
        for key,value in co_occurrence_dict.iteritems():
            if ((word == key.split()[0]) or (word == key.split()[1])):
                pmi_eqn_numerator = (value)/float(N)
                if (key.split()[0] != word):
                    temp_word = key.split()[0]
                else:
                    temp_word = key.split()[1]
                if temp_word==word:
                    temp_dict[temp_word] = 0
                else:
                    temp_sum = generate_sum_occurrence_values(temp_word,co_occurrence_dict)
                    pmi_eqn_denominator1 = (temp_sum)/float(N)
                    temp_sum = generate_sum_occurrence_values(word, co_occurrence_dict)
                    pmi_eqn_denominator2 = (temp_sum)/float(N)
                    pmi = math.log(pmi_eqn_numerator / (float(pmi_eqn_denominator1) * float(pmi_eqn_denominator2)))
                    temp_dict[temp_word] = pmi
        temp_list = []
        for elements in temp_dict.iteritems():
            temp_list.append(elements)
        main_dict[word] = temp_list

def generate_sum_occurrence_values(item,temp_dict):
    sum_values = 0
    for key,value in temp_dict.iteritems():
        if ((item == key.split()[0]) or (item == key.split()[1])):
            sum_values += value
    return sum_values
```

where, all_opinion_words is a list of words, co_occurrence_dict is of the form

```
co_occurrence_dict={'social contemporary': 1, 
                    'earthly indeed': 1,
                    'far mythical': 1,
                    'small higher': 1, 
                    'ideological even': 1, 
                    'certain `magnificent': 1,
                    'back al': 8,
                    'perhaps thin': 1,
                    'never skeptical': 1,
                    'federal small': 1,
                    'difficult most': 1, 
                    'also young': 1, 
                    'ideological ever': 1,
                    'far rather': 1,
                    'able happy': 1}
```

Since I have to process large number of documents, the size of all_opinion_words and  `co_occurrence_dict` is very large. So it takes high execution time. I read that threads can be used to speed up execution. How can I apply threads in this code?

Comment: "I read that threads can be used to speed up execution." [citation needed]

Comment: possible immediate improvement: store your keys as a tuple, instead of splitting the same string over and over.  also, try pypy.

Comment: Python is known for often *not* benefiting from multiple threads, due to the notorious GIL:  http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/03/31/pythons-hardest-problem/?utm_source=feedblitz&utm_medium=FeedBlitzRss&utm_campaign=FeedBlitzRss&utm_content=Python's+Hardest+Problem

Comment: @JeremyFriesner This is true, but in many cases the `multiprocessing` module can be used as a drop-in replacement for `threading`, which gets around the GIL limitation.

Comment: Agreed @dano -- but this question asks specifically about using threads, not processes.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Very true. I've found that a lot of the time, the folks asking questions about `threading` aren't aware `multiprocessing` exists, but find that it's suitable for their needs once they learn about it. So I wanted to throw that info out there, just in case.